# How to get number of children in firebase using android

Tags: android, firebase

```
userdetails
 -KCV32vWQECRlMvlgkGO
    Name: "asdf"
    Phoneid: "1zlkflakfhkf0e8"
    Phoneno: "9478567899"
 -KCV3s-lwv5i-VvFBaxq
    Name: "asas"
    Phoneid: "1c584jbascjasc8"
    Phoneno: "9999999999"
```

I have to get number of children in userdetails. **Example Output : 2**

```
Query queryRef = scoresRef.orderByValue();

        queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                System.out.println("Size " + arg0.getChildrenCount());

            }
});
```

it displaying as 3 two time because it getting each child separately,after getting one child it again goes inside to get another but i need to get as 2
How can I do this ?
Can anyone help me.

Comment: u can make list of that ?

Comment: I am unable to understand. can you explain me

Comment: You might want to loop over those children `for (DataSnapshot child: arg0.getChildren())` and see what they are.

Comment: inside for loop what i have to print?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a ValueEventListener instead of a ChildEventListener